# how to get solve telethon GetLocatedRequest problem?

Tags: python, location, telegram, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

you can visit 1000 different geo locations with 1 API before FloodWaitError but when I try to get people from different locations with GetLocatedRequest method then it does not work well.. GetLocatedRequest method give me same person at NewYork, London or Berlin? Why? How to solve this problem.. Could you help me please?

Comment: You cannot jump 100s of miles in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "fix" raw API methods such as `GetLocatedRequest`. You are directly talking to Telegram's API.

If Telegram's API does not return what you expect, there is nothing you can do about it.